# upload file to SFTP from memory stream

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, azure, sftp

How can i upload file to SFTP server from memory stream. Local Path is not available since am uploading the file from azure blob. as i got the information that .NET does not support the SFTP protocol and so tried 3rd party dlls such as 'SharpSSH','Routrek.granados' and 'WinSCP'. But none are suitable for my scenario. ie bite[] or stream are not supported in the put method.

Can anybody suggest me dlls which are free and suits my scenario or a way I can handle this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know about freeware, but our SecureBlackbox works with streams, including memory streams.

Comment: Is freeware a strict requirement? A few commercial SFTP libs support uploading from a stream for example one from Eldos or Rebex SFTP. Following link show how to do so using our library: http://www.rebex.net/sftp.net/features/single-file-operations.aspx#stream

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can keep using solutions like WinSCP, but instead of trying to use a MemoryStream / byte[], simply download the file locally first:

```
var client = account.CreateCloudBlobClient();
var container = client.GetContainerReference("temp");
var blob = container.GetBlobReferenceFromServer("myblob.zip");

// This assumes you're using a Cloud Service and have a local resource called files
var dropFolder = RoleEnvironment.GetLocalResource("files").RootPath;
var filePath = Path.Combine(dropFolder, "myblob.zip");

// Download blob to a local resource first.
using (var fs = new FileStream(filePath, FileMode.Create))
{
    blob.DownloadToStream(fs);
}

var proc = new Process();
proc.StartInfo.FileName = "winscp.com";
proc.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
proc.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
proc.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.Start();
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("option batch abort");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("option confirm off");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("open mysession");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("ls");
proc.StandardInput.WriteLine("put " + filePath);
proc.StandardInput.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Azure Functions 1 minut
```

```
[FunctionName("Routine")]
        public async Task Routine([TimerTrigger("0 */1 * * * *", RunOnStartup = true)] TimerInfo timer)
        {
            try
            {
                semaphore.Wait();

                Console.WriteLine("Routine Start");

                var hostSftp = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["hostSftp"];
                var portHost = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["portHost"];
                var userSftp = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["userSftp"];
                var password = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"];
                var environment = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["environment"];
                var azureStorage = (string)ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["azureStorage"];

                //Download file from SFTP server
                using (var sftpClient = new SftpClient(hostSftp, Convert.ToInt32(portHost), userSftp, password))
                {
                    sftpClient.Connect();

                    if(sftpClient.IsConnected)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Connected to server: "+hostSftp+" Port: "+portHost);

                        var filePaths = sftpClient.ListDirectory(environment);

                        if(filePaths.Count() > 0)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("There are "+filePaths.Count()+" files to perform the transfer.");

                            foreach (var filePath in filePaths)
                            {
                                Console.WriteLine("FileName: " + filePath.Name );

                                //Download
                                using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                                {
                                    sftpClient.DownloadFile(filePath.FullName, memoryStream);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Downloaded the " + filePaths.Count() + " file from the SFTP server.");

                                    //Upload to azure
                                    await azureProvider.UploadAsync(azureStorage, filePath.Name, memoryStream);
                                    Console.WriteLine(filePaths.Count() + " file uploaded from Azure Storage server.");

                                }

                                //Delete SFTP file
                                if (File.Exists(filePath.FullName))
                                {
                                    File.Delete(filePath.FullName);
                                    Console.WriteLine("Deleted the " + filePaths.Count() + " file on the SFTP server.");
                                }
                            }
                        }

                    }
                    sftpClient.Disconnect();
                }

                Console.WriteLine("Routine Finish");
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
                Console.WriteLine("Routine Finish");
            }
        }
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).